# Fetching cursor location and highlighted text in textarea using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, web

Having a textarea in a form I am trying to do several things:

- fetch the current location of the cursor within the text area
- fetch the current selection within the textarea
- insert some text at the current cursor location
- replace the current selection by some other text

As I am already using JQuery, I'd prefer a solution that works smoothly with that.
Any pointers how to achieve the above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many jQuery plugins for this. Here's a good one I've used before:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools

---

To fetch the current location of the cursor within the text area:

```
$("textarea").getSelection().start;
```

---

To fetch the current selection within the textarea:

```
$("textarea").getSelection();
```

this returns an object like this:

```
{
    start: 1, // where the selection starts
    end: 4, // where the selection ends
    length: 3, // the length of the selection
    text: 'The selected text'
}
```

---

To insert some text at the current cursor location:

```
$("#textarea").insertAtCaretPos("The text to insert");
```

---

To replace the current selection by some other text:

```
$("#textarea").replaceSelection('This text will replace the selection');
```

Comment: This is great, but I wonder why atools plugin has gone obsolete and I cannot find it anywhere except the demo site. Anyone have a replacement or just the code for "replaceselection"?

Comment: @Dexter - [Here's a direct link to the script](http://www.ampparit.com/projects/a-tools/jquery.a-tools-1.5.2.min.js). I just fetched it from the demo.

Comment: Does anything like this exist for selection of regular HTML, where an object like the following can be returned? { start: 1, end: 4, length: 3, text: 'The selected text' }

Comment: @Doug - Everything you need is in the two properties: `selectionStart` & `selectionEnd`: http://jsfiddle.net/pn7Q7/

Comment: Joseph, I'm wondering about selecting text with non-input elements, like regular old div's.

Comment: @doug [The Caret.js demo](http://ichord.github.io/Caret.js/) appears to be a contenteditable=true _div-based_ alternative. Perhaps that might help?