# Handle 'img' click event and insert 'alt' attribute into textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, emoticons

I'm creating a web chat page using PHP and jQuery, and I am adding an emoticon feature, which everything is done except for the jQuery portion. My problem is I'm not getting a click event when I click on the emoticon image. In the handler it is supposed to get the current message value, get the text version of the emoticon from the 'alt' attribute, and set the textbox value to its previous value + the emoticons text appended.

Here is what I tried:

(Each button appears as so: `<img class="embtn" src="emoticons/happy.gif" alt=":)" />`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Insert Emoticon
    $(".embtn").click(function(event){
        var prevMsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        var emotiText = event.target.attr("alt");
        $("#usermsg").val(prevMsg + emotiText);
    });
});
```

How should I go about doing this?

The version of jQuery I am using is 1.3.

Comment: You're not getting a click event at all? Try to isolate your problem - if you're not getting a click event, then none of the code inside the click function is relevant. It would help if you could set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: [The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZTPw/1/) I tried simply using the confirm() method to test it, it still is not working.

Comment: Okay so it handles the click event on my site but not on JSFiddle, strange.

Comment: I fixed it for you - the code needed to be in the document ready function, and you need to choose to include jQuery in the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/mZTPw/3/

Comment: *facepalm* I had it in the document ready function in my actual script but forgot to in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var emotiText = event.target.attr("alt");
```

to:

```
var emotiText = $(event.target).attr("alt");
```

In the future check the console for errors when you are stumped.

Comment: I did not think of checking the console, mainly because I did not know where to find it but in chrome it is right-click inspect-element. And Thanks! The click event does not work in my JSFiddle but I just tested it on my site for good measure and it works now, thank you very much :)

Comment: I often develop with the console open all the time. Glad I can help.

Comment: Well, I don't feel I should post a separate question for this since it would have the same tags and is for the same purpose. How would I go about making the emoticon clickable without losing focus to the textbox? I figure the only way is to explicitly set focus to the textbox in my click function but how would I ensure that the caret is placed exactly where it was (offset by the amount of characters the emoticon inserts), furthermore how would I insert the emoticon at the caret position instead of just at the end of the textbox?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625011/fetching-cursor-location-and-highlighted-text-in-textarea-using-jquery) might help

Comment: Great stuff! I really should have done a search though, but that is EXACTLY what I am looking for.